# Reading multiple numbers from file C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with reading data from .txt file where I have over than million rows which are looking like below:

```
57 1599 1 2.463 1.247 5.644 
58 0 1 3.675 2.175 1.21
```

I have to load data and add every number to a different array or vector.

Here is my code, but it's working too slow.

```
void divideString(std::string text)
{
    std::istringstream iss(text);
    std::vector<std::string> results(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss},
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

    coordinates tmp;

    tmp.x = std::stoi(results[0]);
    tmp.y = std::stoi(results[1]);

    coordinatesCells.push_back(tmp);

    phase.push_back(std::stoi(results[2]));

    orientation tmp2;

    tmp2.k1 = std::stof(results[3]);
    tmp2.k2 = std::stof(results[4]);
    tmp2.k3 = std::stof(results[5]);

    orientationCells.push_back(tmp2);

}


void loadDataFromFile()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("file.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            divideString(line);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
}
```

Another problem is that sometimes I will have different numbers of data in rows.

Do you have any idea how to load fast this data?

Comment: Profile you'r code, and check for the bottleneck.  In any case you don't have to use temporary std::istringstream, if you are using ifstream already (read is buffered). 2. From my experience if performance does mather, it's better to implement you'r parser, using  C standard library instead of C++ io-streams.

Comment: [strtoul](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul), [strtof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) can help you.

Comment: `coordinates tmp; int phase; orientation tmp2; myfile >> tmp.x >> tmp.y >> phase >> tmp2.k1 >> tmp2.k2 >> tmp2.k3;` means you aren't creating and parsing those temporary strings (at the cost of making your format requirements a little looser). But C++ I/O is often very slow, switch to C.